# unable to execute a bash script inside a virtual machine

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, virtualization

I've got a virtual machine created by `docker create -d virtualbox myvm` and I moved there some bash scripts, now I'd like to execute one of them.

How do I go about it?

If I type `docker machine ssh myvm "bash /scripts/myscript.sh"`, it yields the expected error "sh: bash: not found".

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by executing script inside virtual machine? ideally, you should be running docker container and execute scripts inside it. The problem with modifying virtual-machine is, how will these changes be transferred to different environments like staging. have you tried removing "bash" from command?

Comment: Well I'd like to spin up a cluster with docker swarm. I have a few scripts that do just that and I'd like to do it inside some vm, so I created one, make it a swarm manager and now I somehow need to execute the script..I'm pretty new to docker and I'm not really sure I'm doing it right.

Comment: yeah I've just tried it and I this time the error is "env: can't execute 'bash': No such file or directory"

Comment: first check if scripts are actually copied into server and secondly check their permission. You might have to do chmod before executing them.

Comment: @techtrainer yes, all the scripts are where they are supposed to be and I've already executed `chmod +x` on the bash one. So I guess all the permissions are correct. I think the problem is the vm simply doesn't have bash.

Comment: ideally, it should have because bash is even present inside docker containers. did you tried /bin/bash instead of just bash?

Comment: @techtrainer well eventually I've managed to figure it out. Actually a container has the most basic set of packages and extensions needed to do the most basic things. It doesn't have bash but it is possible to install it with tce-ab - a tuny core application browser.

Comment: not sure if thats true. I have used shell scripts earlier inside docker containers and they were fine without any extra installation. Anyways, good to hear you got past this issue.